# iOS - Localizable.strings - NOT working - after Update to 4.5.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, localization

I use only one language at this time, but I want to use the Localizable.strings to prepare my app for the future. After the updating to `Xcode 4.5.1`, my Localizable.strings is not copied to the app - there is no reference in the degugger/builder. I only see "OK_Button" like this in my app.

I use the folder: **de.lproj**
the file: Localizable.strings - has a check at the button for the target and language
all other files as well. At first all looks fine.

**BUT:**
If I have a look at the copy bundle, my 4 Files (Storybord iPhone+ iPad, plist,Localizable.strings) are listed in RED color.

*I cleand, restarted the MAC cleaned the simulaor etc... but nothing works for me.*

What is wrong? What is missing? Any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your string files are in UTF-16 (iOS) with Unix line breaks. Also ensure that your strings are all completed correctly usually with a non-curly quotation mark and semicolon "like this";